Stop-motion or animated show with monster hunters who transform monsters back into humans
My friends and I are looking for a lost animated/maybe stop motion show about a group of people who hunt down monsters and turn them back human.
They were turned into monsters from some type of virus.
They used some kind of catch phrase with "resonance" or "resistance" in it. I think it was made between 2000 and 2010.

Where have your 50 friends looked? What shows have they already discounted?

This question is very terse. You could improve it by going through the checklists here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Matt's Monsters? Monster Buster Club? Trollhunters?

@Valorum I can rule out Trollhunters (grear show btw), because it's not "about" that. Evil trolls are not humans and are usually destroyed. There is one episode about teachers from school being turned by... a beverage if I remember correctly? But the show isn't about this in general.

[Edit] any details you can into your question, particularly if suggestions make you realize something ("No, it can't be Nutterer League because all of the teens were Indonesian. And I think I remember their catchphrase was something about 'resistance'? Or 'persistence'?)

From 2006 to 2012, there was a first person shooter videogame series called Resistance. The relatively primitive animation of the time made human characters look similar to stop-motion claymation.
In the game, Earth is invaded by an alien race called the Chimera who use a virus to transform humans into alien monsters that serve them.  The human resistance battles them and wants to find a cure to the virus.

Game cutscenes




Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! Please consider registering your account, which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your post if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. Registering is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see Why should I register my account?

Generator Rex (2010–2013)?

From Wikipedia:

Five years prior to the events of the series, an explosion occurred on Earth, causing microscopic machines called "nanites" to infiltrate the bodies of all its organic life. When activated, nanites mutate the biology of their hosts; living beings with activated nanites are known as Exponentially Variegated Organisms (E.V.O.). Rex is an amnesiac fifteen-year-old boy and permanent E.V.O. who, unlike most other E.V.O.s, lacks physical deformation but has forgotten his past. He is also able to control his active nanites, allowing him to manifest from his body various bio-mechanical abilities and powers. He also has the unique ability to deactivate nanites inside other E.V.O.s, effectively curing them of their mutations and returning them to normal. Working for Providence under Agent Six and White Knight, Rex uses his unique abilities to stop and cure rampant E.V.O.s.

"They used some kind of catch phrase with "resonance" or "resistance" in it."
Providence perhaps?
From the Generator Rex Wiki:

Providence is a global, clandestine military organization that was created in response to the Nanite Event. Providence's initial function was to contain or kill hostile EVOs. Over time, the organization discovered a teenager named Rex Salazar, a human-passing EVO capable of curing other EVOs. Providence then decided to take a more ethical approach to make curing EVOs priority.


Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This doesn't look like it's stop-motion animation though?

@DavidW "animated/maybe stop motion". It's definitely animated. Also noticed none of the other answers is stop motion

Might it be Vor-Tech: Undercover Conversion Squad?


The VOR-Tech Undercover Conversion Squad is a group of secret agents led by Hudson Roarke. Their mission is to stop Hudson's older brother Damian Roarke—known as Lord Matrix—and his evil "Bio Mechs" from infecting the world with a techno-infectious plague. Similar to the M.A.S.K. franchise, the VOR-Tech agents had special masks and transforming vehicles, with special computer systems that imbue them and their vehicles with special powers.



If so, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/191110/people-with-transforming-vehicles-fighting-alien-like-humanoids-with-one-hero-be/191220#191220

I also remember so kind of catch phrase with resonance or resistance in it and it’s not any of the shows stated  we have also check websites like the wiki and this one along with others

Also I believe it was made somewhere In the 2000-2010
